# Type.GetType() dynamic string return null

Tags: c#

I´m using `Type.GetType()` to create a instance.

This works:

```
 var type = Type.GetType("Test.ClassServices.HowService, Test");
```

But, this doesn´t work. It returns `null`:

```
 var name = "How";
 var type = Type.GetType("Test.ClassServices."+name+"Service, Test");
```

Comment: GetType does not create an instance, it returns a Type object that represents the specified type. As for null, are you sure the assembly can be found and is loaded and the namespace is correct?

Comment: I tried this in .NET 4 and had no problems. So double check the code for typos.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not any typo's in 2-nd case? I suppose, value of `name` variable is calculated, are you sure that this is done correctly(BTW, casing matters)?

Comment: I agreed with @Jetti, the code is equivalent. Must work. Try typing it out again. Perhaps a Unicode funkiness. Also, create the string into it's own variable, then assert it to be equal to the hardcoded version.

Comment: Well, I had an error in the database. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No-repro. Run this sample:

```
var hardCodedWorking = Type.GetType("System.String");

var stringName = "String";
var concatenatedWorking = Type.GetType("System." + stringName);

var badStringName = "string";
var concatenatedNull = Type.GetType("System." + badStringName);
```

From [Type.GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) on MSDN:

> Gets the Type with the specified name, performing a case-sensitive
>   search.

Based on that and my example above, I believe it's most likely that the value of `name` isn't matching the name of the class perfectly.